# Client-server, TCPsocket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server

Here is the code of a Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;



public class Client_TCP {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Socket client_socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1025);

    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(client_socket.getOutputStream());
    os.writeBytes("Hi Server, I'm the Client. How are you?");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream()));

    String line = new String("");
    String supportLine=new String("");

    while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
    supportLine = line;

    System.out.println(supportLine);

    os.close();
    br.close();
    client_socket.close();

    }

}
```

Here is the code of the server which we will connect the client above:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;



    public class ServerTCP {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server_Socket = new ServerSocket();
        server_Socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(1025));

        Socket welcomeSocket = server_Socket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection done on: " + welcomeSocket.getPort());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(welcomeSocket.getInputStream()));

        String line= new String("");
        String supportLine = new String("");

        while((line=br.readLine()) != null ) {

            supportLine=supportLine + line; 
        }

        System.out.println(supportLine);

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(welcomeSocket.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("I'm fine thanks! And you?");

        br.close();
        os.close();
        welcomeSocket.close();          
    }

}
```

As you can see the Client sends the message: *"Hi Server, I'm the Client. How are you?"*
The Server receives the message and replay:*"I'm fine thanks! And you?"*.
Client's message arrives to the Server rightly. But, Server's message, instead, does not arrive to the Client.

I need your help to fix this problem. Can you help me?

Thank you, bye.

Comment: I think your problem might be caused by a race condition. The simplest way to resolve that issue is to put a timeout before reading your streams, and ensure that sending in both processes happens before reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should flush the OutputStream after sending the data if you expect to read/write immediately:

```
os.flush();
```

Second, see the API for [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Since your Client (and Server) is not sending the end of line character the Server (and Client) may block trying to read the Line. Include this when sending the data if the server (and/or client) expects it.